# Why content of EAX differs?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have 2 assembly methods:

1. `DWToHex    PROTO:DWORD` modifies binary integer number of type `DWORD` passed as in input parameter
   inside `EAX` into a hexadecimal representation, pointer to which is passed inside the single parameter. It is function used for debug purpose and it works fine.
2. `ProcA      PROTO:DWORD` - does nothing except for corrupting the content of `EAX` below is the code:
   **(sorry for the formatting -c seems like the regular code formatting did not work here)**

; #########################################################################

```
`.386                       ; set processor type`
`.model flat, stdcall       ; memory model & calling convention`
`option casemap :none       ; case sensitive`

`.code`
```

; #########################################################################

```
procA public addrSTD:DWORD

ret

ProcA   endp
```

; #########################################################################

```
end
```

**Here is the debug trace:**

```
.data

MsgBoxCaption4 db  "before calling", 0
MsgBoxCaption5 db  "after   calling", 0

.data?

N       DWORD   ?
NTXT        db 16 dup(?)

.code

mov eax, N
invoke  cx_DWToHex, addr NTXT
invoke  MessageBox, NULL, addr NTXT, addr MsgBoxCaption4, MB_OK ; show eax as hexadecimal

mov eax, N                      ;   ***** point A ****
invoke  ProcA, addr sdt         ;   ***** point B ****
;   mov eax, N
invoke  cx_DWToHex, addr NTXT
invoke  MessageBox, NULL, addr NTXT, addr MsgBoxCaption5, MB_OK ; show eax as hexadecimal
```

...........................................................................................

**Question:**
Why the content of `EAX` in point A in point B is not the same?

Comment: You ask what ProcA does to eax without posting its code.  Looks like it changed eax.  If you set a breakpoint on point A then you actually see the return value of MessageBox.

Comment: @HansPassant procA code is posted right below (2) after the bold text

Comment: @Hans Passat, addrSTD is not the name of the method. the misspelled method name is `proc` instead of `procA` - i will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `invoke` directive you use for calling `ProcA` is supposed to get the address of 'sdt', and push it on the stack. More than likely, it generates code similar to

```
lea eax, sdt
push eax
call ProcA
```

which destroys the contents of `eax`. You can verify this by looking at the disassembly of the generated code.

Comment: Which would be perfectly okay under stdcall conventions since EAX does not need to be preserved (and for functions which return something is used for the return value anyway).